# Delayed checkpoint in ProcessEventsAsync

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, event-processor-host

EventHub's `IEventProcessor` interface has the following method:

```
Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
```

I want to postaggregate messages I receive from event-hub in `TPL.DataFlow`, because original batches are too small. By doing so I would have to checkpoint events somewhere in data-flow pipeline and it obviously happens long after the method has returned.

Q.1: Can I use `context` argument after `ProcessEventsAsync` has returned? How safe is that?
Q.2: Is there a better way of doing what I want?

Answer (score 0):

After researching event-processor source code I came to conclusion that it is not a good idea. PartitionContext is mutable and does not seem to be thread-safe, so calling its methods concurrently might corrupt its state.